# IVT from FTC and Darboux

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'd like to prove that the intermediate value theorem (IVT) using the fundamental theorem of calculus and Darboux's theorem. The latter says

> If $f'(a)<k<f'(b)$, then there exists some $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=k$. it is true even when $f'$ is not continuous.

Although I know the formal proof of IVT using the least upper bound property, I wanna prove this thm again only using above the theorems.

Is there any good idea to prove this? Could you give me any hint, not whole proof?

Comment: You basically want to prove that every function which is continuous on $(a,b)$ is the derivative of some function $F:(a,b)\to \Bbb R$. This is FTC.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I assume f is continuous, and then f is integrable and F is continuous. Since F' = f , Applying Darboux's theorem, then if F'(a) < k < F'(b), I can find some c between a and b such that F'(c) = k = f(c). so I can find such c in (a, b). proof is done, am I right?

Comment: Your approach seems fine, but it is unnecessarily complicated. One should always strive for simpler proofs which are accessible to a wider audience.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Thank you for your advice. But I can't find which point of my method is complicated or abundant. Could you point it out? Then I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: You are using a difficult theorem namely that every continuous function is Riemann integrable and then the FTC and further Darboux. The result is easily proved without using any notion of integral or derivative. Complication is not in the nature of argument, but rather in using more powerful theorems to prove a simple result. An analogy is to deduce the irrationality of $e, \pi$ from their transcendence.